# Are btrfs reads round-robin or throughput maximising?

Tags: linux, btrfs, bcache

Does `btrfs` prefer to read from a faster device if one is available?

My reason for asking:

I have a `btrfs` RAID 1 on spinning rust. I want to use `bcache` for increased performance, and hope to only cache one of the drives (for greater cache coverage) if `btrfs` is smart enough to prefer reads from the `bcache` device over the spinning rust device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, at the moment btrfs raid1 chose the device to read from based on the pid of the process (ie: if the pid is even read from disk 0, if the pid is odd read from disk 1).

Anyway, recently this has been worked out and a new framework to add new read policies has been added.

This work has not yet been merged in mainline kernel but will probably be soon.

Comment: If you remember when it's merged, I'd appreciate the heads-up!